# JDBC PreparedStatement with aggregate function on dynamic column in Select clause

Tags: java, jdbc, max, prepared-statement

I was trying to come with an utility where I can get max of data length in each column of a table.

1. I have list of columns in a list.
2. I go over each list.
3. Execute below prepared statement.

   ```
   String sql = "select max(datalength(?)) from Positions"; 

   for(Iterate over list of column names) 
    {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, StringUtils.trim(columnName));
        ResultSet rs =  preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
           int length1 = rs.getInt(1);
           //print column name and max data length
        }
     }
   ```

Seems the prepared statement with max function taking the dynamic column not working. Its gives incorrect values.

Can prepared statement work with dynamic column in select clause.

Comment: No, the placeholders can't be used to dynamically replace a column name (or a table name) .

Answer (score 0):

Try the below..

```
Select max(length(<column_name>)) as max_length

From <Table_name>;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.